# JavaFX Custom Table Cell - Strange behavior

Tags: javafx-8

I have this code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class Example extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        TableView<Color> table = new TableView<>();
        ObservableList<Color> colors = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        table.setItems(colors);
        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Color, Color> column = new TableColumn<>();
        column.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(param.getValue()));

        column.setCellFactory(param ->
        {
            ObservableList<Color> menuColors = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            menuColors.addAll(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE);
            return new ComboBoxTableCell(menuColors);
        });

        Button button = new Button("Add row");
        button.setOnAction(event -> colors.add(Color.BLACK));

        VBox box = new VBox(table, button);
        table.getColumns().add(column);
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(box));
        stage.show();
    }

    public class ComboBoxTableCell extends TableCell<Color, Color>
    {
        private ComboBox<Color> comboBox;

        public ComboBoxTableCell(ObservableList<Color> colors)
        {
            comboBox = createFancyComboBox(colors);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Color item, boolean empty)
        {
            if (item == null || empty)
                setGraphic(null);
            else
                setGraphic(comboBox);
        }
    }

    private ComboBox<Color> createFancyComboBox(ObservableList<Color> colors)
    {
        ComboBox<Color> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(colors);
        Callback<ListView<Color>, ListCell<Color>> factory = list -> new ColorSquare();
        comboBox.setCellFactory(factory);
        comboBox.setButtonCell(factory.call(null));
        comboBox.setValue(colors.get(0));
        return comboBox;
    }

    public static class ColorSquare extends ListCell<Color>
    {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Color item, boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(18, 18);
            if (item != null)
            {
                rect.setFill(item);
                setGraphic(rect);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If I try to run it, click on the button, change the color to for Green and click 8 times on the button, the green square will disapper.

How do I fix this and why is it happening? The real code isn't much different from this, this is the only problem I have. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that at times the rerendering of a table cell doesn't work right after a certain number of attempts. I had one where I was updating a remaining amount when the user entered a value in another cell.

To solve this I would toggle visibility of the column.

```
column.setVisible(false);
column.setVisible(true);
```

I would do this immediately after the action that changed the value in the cell.

It's a hack but seems to work.

Comment: Where exactly should I put this please?

Comment: You said this is happening when you click the button 8 times. I would put this code in you event handler for the button click.

Comment: I see. But it didn't help. The problem is somewhere else, the clicks don't have to be fast.